# What is Routedata.Values[""]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, routedata

I am surprised to see that there is no article which answers this question with any details. I have few questions related to `RouteData.Values[""]`.

I saw this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = string.Format("{0}---{1}--{2}",
        RouteData.Values["Controller"],
        RouteData.Values["action"],
        RouteData.Values["id"]);

    return View();
}
```

Here it is basically reading values which potentially sounds like "Meta-data" of the controller. Or is it something that View can also pass to Controller?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RouteData.Values is used for accessing the values/querystring values inserted by the classes handling routing. 
In your case, the route defined in your route configuration class has additional parameters to which arguments would have been provided. 
The parameters are controller, action, id. 
The arguments to these parameters would have been provided somewhere in your code.

**It makes more sense when you start a few levels higher, so you know what you are searching for.**

1. The Global.asax.cs

   ```
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       routingActions.RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   }
   ```
2. Another class defines the above method:

   ```
   public void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.MapPageRoute("searchdetails", "searchdetails/{orderID}/{PageIndex}/{PageSize}", "~/View/SearchDetails.aspx");
   }
   ```
3. The following code creates a hyperlink. The main difference is the way the HREF is constructed. 
   In this case, the "searchdetails" is defined in the class which contains my route configuration.

   ```
   linkToDetails.HRef = GetRouteUrl("searchdetails",
                   new
                   {
                       orderID = someOrderID,
                       PageIndex = currentPageIndex,
                       PageSize = PageSize
                   });
   ```
4. Finally, the target page needs to use this information passed in step 3.
   This is where we use **RouteData.Values[""]**

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var _orderid = Page.RouteData.Values["orderID"].ToString();
       var _PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Page.RouteData.Values["PageIndex"]);
       var _PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Page.RouteData.Values["PageSize"]);
   }
   ```

Comment: Why Page_Load in an obviously MVC application?

Comment: @Stack0verflow We have a similarly setup in a web forms site.  You can do it, it is just not the default (unlike MVC).

Answer (score 7):

RouteData is an attribute of the basic Controller class, so you can access RouteData in any controller. RouteData contains routing information for the current request. You can use RouteData to get controller, operation or parameter information as shown below.

Note that you need to convert to the appropriate data type or use the implicit type variable var.