# ASP.NET - Read MapPageRoute parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

So I'm trying to learn how `MapPageRoute` works, and I was wondering: "How do you read the parameters given in an url?".

So far I've tried this:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(
           "exportparts",
           "exportparts/{company}/{ditono}",
           "~/Source/1UI/ExportParts.aspx");
```

But when I try to read the parameters like this:

```
string company = (string)Page.RouteData.DataTokens["company"];
```

the dictionary is empty. How do I read parameters?

Comment: I think the for this value to be not empty the url should look like this: 

www.someurl.com/ExportParts.aspx?company=Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Suppose you want to access the values ? It's done like below
`Page.RouteData.Values["company"].ToString();`

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823084/what-is-routedata-values)